# Create Folder with ZIPed Images Android

Tags: android, kotlin, permissions, zip

I need to create a zipped folder of a folder which contains .jpg and is stored in DIRECTORY_PICTURES. Below is my current code.

```
    val picPath = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES  + "/" + PaUnitEquipmentFragment.equipComp + " " + PaUnitEquipmentFragment.report + " " + date)
    var data = ByteArray(1024)
    if(picPath.listFiles() != null ) {
        picPath.listFiles().forEach {
            var outDest = FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES  + "/" + PaUnitEquipmentFragment.equipComp + " " + PaUnitEquipmentFragment.report + " " + date + ".zip"))
            var out = ZipOutputStream(outDest)
            var fi = FileInputStream(it)
            var origin = BufferedInputStream(fi)
            var entry = ZipEntry(it.toString())
            out.putNextEntry(entry)
            origin.copyTo(out, 1024)
        }
    }
```

I'm getting a EPERM (Operation not permitted) error and I don't understand why.

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/ PA External Visual Inspection 02-13-2024.zip: open failed: EPERM (Operation not permitted)
```

Are there any errors in my code that I'm missing? Do I need to add permissions to my Manifest? I'm targeting API 34, Min 33 - my understanding is that I don't need to request WRITE permissions for this level. The folder which contains the images that I'm trying to zip is also created from within the app using the MediaStore and I don't receive any permission errors when doing that.

Comment: You cannot write zip files to the Pictures directory as that directory is for image files only. Use the Documents directory instead.

Comment: If you are on Android 11+ you should use scoped storage instead of direct file operations.

Comment: I am using scoped storage.

@blackapps, oddly enough, when I switched this to Documents, I didn't receive the error, but the folder was not showing on my devices File Explorer. I changed it to Downloads, and it worked perfectly. There must be something that masks .zip files from showing in the file explorer that I could not figure out.